# How to create multiple containers with jade

Tags: agent, agents-jade

I want to create 2 containers but the agent of my second container shows a problem

> ERROR: Agent robot10 died without being properly terminated !!!

when i delete the second container it works

```
Runtime Instance = Runtime.instance(); Instance.setCloseVM(true);
ProfileImpl Profile = new ProfileImpl(true);
Profile.setParameter(Profile.CONTAINER_NAME, "Pacman");
Profile.setParameter(Profile.MAIN_HOST, "localhost");



            AgentContainer Conteneur = Instance.createAgentContainer(Profile);

            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
AgentController Agent = Conteneur.createNewAgent("robot" + String.valueOf(i), "package1.robot", Parametres1);
Agent.start();
}
AgentContainer Conteneur1 = Instance.createAgentContainer(Profile);


AgentController Agent = Conteneur1.createNewAgent("robot10" , "package1.robot", new Object[] {});
Agent.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code, you do not update the Profile of your containers and use the same Name for 2 different containers, which is wrong.

```
    //create container1 
    String containerName="Mycontainer1";
    ProfileImpl pContainer = new ProfileImpl(PLATFORM_IP, PLATFORM_PORT, PLATFORM_ID);
    pContainer.setParameter(Profile.CONTAINER_NAME,containerName);

    System.out.println("Launching container "+pContainer);
    ContainerController containerRef = rt.createAgentContainer(pContainer);

    //create container2 
    containerName="Mycontainer2";
    pContainer = new ProfileImpl(PLATFORM_IP, PLATFORM_PORT, PLATFORM_ID);
    pContainer.setParameter(Profile.CONTAINER_NAME,containerName);
    System.out.println("Launching container "+pContainer);
    containerRef = rt.createAgentContainer(pContainer);
```

For a running example with 3 containers, see : https://gitlab.com/startjade/startJade

Answer (score 0):

It is still showing errors 
Here is the code

```
    package package1;

import jade.Boot;
import jade.core.AID;
import jade.core.Agent;
import jade.core.Profile;
import static jade.core.Profile.PLATFORM_ID;
import jade.core.ProfileImpl;
import jade.domain.DFService;
import jade.domain.FIPAAgentManagement.DFAgentDescription;
import jade.domain.FIPAException;
import jade.lang.acl.ACLMessage;
import jade.wrapper.AgentContainer;
import jade.wrapper.AgentController;
import jade.wrapper.ContainerController;
import jade.wrapper.StaleProxyException;


import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class launch extends Agent {
   static DFAgentDescription agentDescription;private static AID aid;
    static ACLMessage message1, message2;
        launch() throws FIPAException{

    agentDescription = new DFAgentDescription();
            agentDescription.setName(getAID());

            DFService.register(this, agentDescription);
        DFService.register(this, agentDescription);

        }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws StaleProxyException  {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        try {
            String[] arg = { "-gui","ClusteringAgent:multi.agent_clustering.ClusteringAgent" };
            Boot.main(arg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }





        jade.core.Runtime rt = jade.core.Runtime.instance(); rt.setCloseVM(true);
     String containerName="Mycontainer1";
    ProfileImpl pContainer = new ProfileImpl(true);
    pContainer.setParameter(Profile.CONTAINER_NAME,containerName);

    System.out.println("Launching container "+pContainer);
    ContainerController containerRef = rt.createAgentContainer(pContainer);
  AgentController Agent = containerRef.createNewAgent("robot" + String.valueOf(1), "package1.launch", new Object[] { 2});
                Agent.start();


    //create container2 
    containerName="Mycontainer2";
    pContainer = new ProfileImpl( true);
    pContainer.setParameter(Profile.CONTAINER_NAME,containerName);
    System.out.println("Launching container "+pContainer);
    containerRef = rt.createAgentContainer(pContainer); 
     AgentController Agent1 = containerRef.createNewAgent("robot" + String.valueOf(2), "package1.launch", new Object[] {2});
                Agent.start();
    }
}
```

the error showing is :

```
Exception in thread "main" jade.wrapper.StaleProxyException: Illegal access exception in createAgent() [nested java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class jade.core.management.AgentManagementService$CommandTargetSink can not access a member of class package1.launch with modifiers ""]
    at jade.wrapper.ContainerController.createNewAgent(Unknown Source)
```